# N/A and Slider in Choropleth Maps Vega Lite

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps, vega-lite

Updated Question: [Slider in Choropleth Map Vega Lite not linking to the Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173390/slider-in-choropleth-map-vega-lite-not-linking-to-the-data)

I'm trying to fix up two things for my maps:

1. I would like to create a slider for the year on my map
2. However, I do not have the data for all of my countries. And I would not want my maps to have holes, as if the countries do not exist. Thus, I want the color of the countries that have no data to be different. or probably made it as lines. Example:
   [image]

I will really appreciate the help. I'm so confused how vega lite never shows where our error is, so I'm struggling as a beginner.

Below is my code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  
    "width": 1050,
    "height": 500,
    "data": {
      "url":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/Edu%20Data/mean-years-of-schooling-long-run.csv",
      
    },
    "projection": {"type": "equalEarth"},
    "layer": [
      {
        "transform": [
          {
            "calculate": "'No data available in ' + datum.properties.NAME",
            "as": "no_data"
          }
        ],
        "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "lightgray", "stroke": "white", "strokeWidth": 0.002},
        "encoding": {"tooltip": {"field": "no_data"}}
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/ne/ne_100m_ocean.json",
          "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "oceans"}
        },
        "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "#f2f2f2"}
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/ne/ne_110m_graticules_30.json",
          "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_graticules_30"}
        },
        "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": null, "stroke": "lightgray"}
      },
      {
        "transform": [
          {
            "lookup": "properties.NAME",
            "from": {
              "data": {
                "url":  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/ne/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.json",
                "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"}
              },
              "key": "properties.NAME"
            },
        {"filter": "datum.year == year_selection"}
          }
        ],
        "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white"},
        "params": [{
            "name": "year_selection",
            "value": 2020,
            "bind": {
              "input": "range",
              "min": 1880,
              "max": 2040,
              "step": 1,
              "name": "Year Selection: "}
    }],

        "encoding": {
            "color": {
                "field": "Years",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "scale": {
                  "type": "threshold",
                  "domain":  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
                  "range": ["#fff5f0", "#fee5d9", "#fcbba1", "#fc9272", "#fb6a4a", "#ef3b2c", "#cb181d", "#99000d"]
                }
              },
          "tooltip": [
            {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "Country"},
            {
              "field": "Years",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Avg years of Schooling Years",
              "format": ",.0f"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```