# Slider in Choropleth Map Vega Lite not linking to the Data

Tags: javascript, maps, vega-lite

I'm trying to create a choropleth map with slider based on year. However, the data just doesn't want to link with the slider.

I got two different codes here:

**1. The map shows that no data is available.
I suspect the error here is in line 57-76, in the filter area**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "title": "Average Year of Schooling",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 400,
    "data": {
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/Edu%20Data/mean-years-of-schooling-long-run.csv",     
     },
     
    "projection": {"type": "equalEarth"},
    
    "params": [
                {
                "name": "year_selection",
                "value": 2020,
                "bind": {
                    "input": "range",
                    "min": 1870,
                    "max": 2040,
                    "step": 1,
                    "name": "Year Selection: "
                }
                }
              ],

    "layer": [
                
                {"data": {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/3_choropleth_map/js/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.topojson",
                    "format": {
                                "type": "topojson",
                                "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"
                                }
                            },
                            "transform":[
                                {
                                    "calculate": "'Data not available in ' + datum.properties.NAME", "as": "note"
                                }
                                        ],
                                "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "lightgray", "stroke": "white"},
                                "encoding": {"tooltip": {"field": "note"}}
                },
                {
                    "data": {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/7_others/oceans.topojson",
                    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "oceans"}
                    },
                    "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "skyblue"}
                },
                {
                    "data": {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/2_symbol_map/js/WorldMapWithGraticules.topojson",
                    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_graticules_30"}
                    },
                    "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": null, "stroke": "lightgray"}
                },
                {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/Edu%20Data/mean-years-of-schooling-long-run.csv"
                    },
                    "transform": [
                      {
                        "lookup": "Country",
                        "from": {
                          "data": {
                            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/3_choropleth_map/js/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.topojson",
                            "format": {
                              "type": "topojson",
                              "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"
                            }
                          },
                          "key": "properties.NAME"
                        }
                      },
                      {"filter": "datum.Year == year_selection"}
                    ],
                    
        
                    "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white"},
                    
                    "encoding": {
                    "color": {
                        "field": "Years",
                        "type": "quantitative",
                        "scale": {
                        "type": "threshold",
                        "domain":  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
                    "range": ["#fff5f0", "#fee5d9", "#fcbba1", "#fc9272", "#fb6a4a", "#ef3b2c", "#cb181d", "#99000d"]
                        }
                    },
          
                "tooltip": [
                    {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "Country"},
                    {"field": "Year", "type": "quantitative"},
                    {
                    "field": "Years",
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "format": ".2f"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "config": {}
  }
```

**2. The map here shows only the data in year 1980, despite the slider. Meanwhile, I have other data in other years, that is why I want the slider.
Suspected error is because I haven't put on the filter here. I'm not too sure where to put.**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "title": "Average Year of Schooling",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 400,
    "data": {
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/Edu%20Data/mean-years-of-schooling-long-run.csv",     
     },
     
    "projection": {"type": "equalEarth"},
    
    "params": [
                {
                "name": "year_selection",
                "value": 2020,
                "bind": {
                    "input": "range",
                    "min": 1870,
                    "max": 2040,
                    "step": 1,
                    "name": "Year Selection: "
                }
                }
              ],

    "layer": [
                
                {"data": {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/3_choropleth_map/js/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.topojson",
                    "format": {
                                "type": "topojson",
                                "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"
                                }
                            },
                            "transform":[
                                {
                                    "calculate": "'Data not available in ' + datum.properties.NAME", "as": "note"
                                }
                                        ],
                                "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "lightgray", "stroke": "white"},
                                "encoding": {"tooltip": {"field": "note"}}
                },
                {
                    "data": {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/7_others/oceans.topojson",
                    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "oceans"}
                    },
                    "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "skyblue"}
                },
                {
                    "data": {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/2_symbol_map/js/WorldMapWithGraticules.topojson",
                    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_graticules_30"}
                    },
                    "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": null, "stroke": "lightgray"}
                },
                {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Clairinechendra/FIT3179_A2/main/Edu%20Data/mean-years-of-schooling-long-run.csv"
                    },
                    "transform": [
                      {
                        "lookup": "Country",
                        "from": {
                          "data": {
                            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIT3179/Vega-Lite/main/3_choropleth_map/js/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.topojson",
                            "format": {
                              "type": "topojson",
                              "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"
                            }
                          },
                          "key": "properties.NAME"
                        }
                      },
                      {"filter": "datum.Year == year_selection"}
                    ],
                    
        
                    "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white"},
                    
                    "encoding": {
                    "color": {
                        "field": "Years",
                        "type": "quantitative",
                        "scale": {
                        "type": "threshold",
                        "domain":  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
                    "range": ["#fff5f0", "#fee5d9", "#fcbba1", "#fc9272", "#fb6a4a", "#ef3b2c", "#cb181d", "#99000d"]
                        }
                    },
          
                "tooltip": [
                    {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "Country"},
                    {"field": "Year", "type": "quantitative"},
                    {
                    "field": "Years",
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "format": ".2f"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "config": {}
  }
```

Appreciate the help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this for PowerBI or stand-alone? I don't have time to look but I did something similar here if you have a look at my Covid map. https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Comment: @DavideBacci This is actually for vega-lite. But still, thank you for sending me the link.